# casperjs, might need another click method?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, click, casperjs

I am new to casperjs, and as far as I have learned so far, there are only two click methods that can trigger a mouse action:

- `click()` requires a selector
- `clickLabel()` requires "label" between tags

The website I am dealing with right now has dynamic "tabs", by clicking each tab, a javascript submit is triggered, there is no "class", "id" or "label" associated with each tab, except for "pic" element:

```
<a href="javascript:submitTab('search6')" tabindex="6">
    <img src="image6off.gif" name="imag6" height="6" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" onmouseover="nbGroup('over','imag6','image6on.gif','image6on.gif',1);" onmouseout="nbGroup('out');" onclick="nbGroup('down','group1','imag6','image6off.gif',1); submitTab('search6')" alt="New Search">
</a>
```

I tried to use `clickLabel()` but failed.

YES, I can use XPath, however the problem is the number of tabs is dynamic depending on the available information for each record, so in this case "new search" could be tab 6 for this record but tab 4 in another, tab 8 in yet another.

YES, I could try to write a "loop" to loop through all available tabs, potentially, however, if there is one method of click which combine the

```
waitForResource()
```

that would be great, since I can use the "image6on.gif" to tell the program which image or tab to click, apparently, for this website, I found out that each different javascript submit tab program is uniquely associated with one "image#on/off.gif"

I hope some contributor for casperjs can easily implement this method to deal this kind of situation.

Comment: by the way, if there is another way to get around it, please teach me, specifically, how to click on the specific tab whose tab number is not associated with the field of record behind of it, but i want specific field of record rather the No.# tab's information, i hope i am specific enough

Comment: thank you very much for your editing work, rgettman

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure if this is what you want, but you can get the tab based on the `tabindex` attribute with:

```
casper.click("a[tabindex='6']");
```

**Edit**: Hack I threw together based on your comment below:

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
  var attr = document.querySelector('img[alt="New Search"]').parentNode.getAttribute('tabindex');
  __utils__.click('a[tabindex="' + attr + '"]');
});
```

`casper.thenEvaluate()` allows you to execute javascript on the remote page.

`__utils__` is injected into each page loaded as an extra set of functions that you can use.

Comment: first of all, thank you very much for your answer, "tabindex="6" is not necessarily always associated with "new search", each tab has different information, if i want to click on "new search", the "new search" tab could be tabindex="6" for this record but tabindex="8" for the next one, so i cannot use tabindex to make sure i will always click on "new search", one thing i found out is that the image associated with the tab ""image#on/off.gif" is uniquely associated with the content, such as "new search", therefore, if i could specify the resource i am clicking, the problem would be resolved!

Comment: Updated so that it grabs the tabindex of the image's parent and then clicks on that element.

Comment: my god, so many genius are here and it seems nothing is unachievable, thanks you very much, hexid

Comment: sure, why not, and i learned something new, i am too old but i have to learn java

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a contributor to CasperJS. From my point of view the `clickLabel` function is already too much. I cannot remember that I actually used it, because most of the time there is something that prevents an exact string match.

You are right, it is a valid argument to add a new click function to CasperJS. In my opinion it is better to use the provided XPath capability to do that. You can even create the function for your use:

```
casper.clickByImg = function(imgRes){
    var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
    this.click(x("//a/img[contains(@href,"+imgRes+")]/.."));
    return this;
};
```

See: minimal overhead.

You can even go this far as to match the image by a regular expression with more overhead.

```
casper.clickByImgRegexp = function(regexp){
    var hrefs = this.getElementsAttribute("a > img", "href");
    for(var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
        if (hrefs[i].match(regexp)) {
            this.clickByImg(hrefs[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```